# Is there a reason the Java library designers explicitly required TreeMap to be a red/black tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, language-lawyer

I was reading over the [Javadoc for the `TreeMap` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and was surprised to see that it explicitly requires that `TreeMap` use a red/black tree as its internal implementation. Not only that, it specifically singles out a particular implementation strategy for the red/black tree:

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

I found this unusual because I haven’t seen anything else comparable to this in the Java documentation (with the exception of very precisely named types like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, for example). If you look at [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), for example, there’s no mention of what sorting algorithm should be used. The [`HashMap` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn’t specify whether the internal representation uses chained hashing, linear probing, Robin Hood hashing, etc.

I was especially curious about this because I’m used to reading the C++ spec, where the implementation of `std::map` is constrained only by complexity guarantees and restrictions on iterator invalidation. The C++ `std::map` could in principle be implemented as a red/black tree, or a scapegoat tree, or a splay tree, or even a deterministic skiplist.

Is there a *documented* reason why the Javadoc here is so specific about the internal implementation of `TreeMap` that would distinguish it from other types like `HashMap` or other algorithmic primitives like sorting or searching? I know for the C ISO spec that there's a [rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) explaining many of the decisions that the committee made, and if there's something analogous for the decision here, I'd love to see what it is.

Comment: Possibly interesting question but somewhat off-topic.  You'd have to ask the language designers and implementers.

Comment: `TreeMap` is an old class, so this is probably a legacy issue. `TreeMap` appears in Java 1.2, released in 1998. The code for the class has been written some time in 1997..1998. Java was far from its top-league #1 spot in TIOBE index. It was #15 in 1997, the spot hotly contested today by Scratch, Object Pascal, and R. SUN microsystems hired fresh-out-of-school kids to write the library. Kids picked up the last book from their data structures class, implemented `TreeMap`, and wrote the docs. 20 years later it looks funny; back than it was a race for the market share, which Java won.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Do you have some evidence for any of that?

Comment: @EJP 15-th spot for Java as of 1997 is on TIOBE index web site. Release date of Java 1.2 is on wikipedia. The fact that `TreeMap` is added in 1.2 is in Javadocs. I found 1.2 Javadocs to confirm that RB-tree language is already there. I was wrong about fresh-out-of-school kids: Josh Bloch, who coded up the class, worked as a senior system designer for seven years before joining SUN.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well that's what I was really asking about: the 'fresh-out-of-school kids' claim. I was using Java in 1997 and I'm well aware of when 1.2 and `TreeMap` appeared.

Comment: Why was this reopened? Did it suddenly become not opinion based? Even though it hasn't been edited? and has attracted nothing but baseless speculation? @meagar

Comment: @EJP It was flagged for reopening by its author, and the answer to *"Is there a documented reason why the Javadoc..."* doesn't seem like an opinion to me. It wasn't meant to be a statement of any kind, just seemed like a reasonable reopen request to me.

Comment: Collections.sort doesn't mention the sorting algorithm, but [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-byte:A-) does. Note that Collections.sort was changed from [the Java 7 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort\(java.util.List\)), possibly because it was deemed too restrictive for the many types of Lists. At that point one might consider HashMap to be the odd one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a documented reason why the Javadoc here is so specific about the internal implementation of TreeMap that would distinguish it from other types like HashMap or other algorithmic primitives like sorting or searching?

In short, there isn't.

> I know for the C ISO spec that there's a rationale document explaining many of the decisions that the committee made, and if there's something analogous for the decision here, I'd love to see what it is.

There are no such (public) documents that discuss such decisions for Java.  At least, none that I have come across ... in the past 20+ years.

1. The Java designers do not operate the same was as the formal standards groups for C, C++ and ECMAscript.
2. Since the javadocs are embedded in the source code, actual changes to them must be made by people with access to the core codebase.  This would be subject to a procedure similar to code review, rather than standards writing processes.

It can be a bit different for some of the JSR teams, but it is really up to the respective team leader to decide how much (or little) rationale they choose to document.  Different JSRs operate very differently.

---

The best anyone can say at this stage is that the real reasons are lost in time.  We don't actually know for sure who wrote those javadocs originally, and who has been maintaining them.

The one thing that we do know is that over time Sun / Oracle have taken different stances on the amount of implementation detail to include in the javadocs.  Examples are the javadocs for `HashMap` and `Arrays.sort`, where the amount of detail has changed with different versions.

Comment: VG but as a matter of fact the Javadoc is maintained separately and only merged into the source code for source-release purposes. At least that's how it was done prior to OpenJDK.